# Better term to put on a label of a bottle of milk to describe that it's 'made' in a particular geographic location

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, synonyms, past-participles

While waiting for the kettle to boil this morning, I was idling and reading the label on the bottle of milk and was struck by the declaration: "Permeate free, made in WA". Here's a shot of the label for proper context:

[image: The label in question]

It's clear that they want to state that the milk is produced in this state, but it sounds odd to me to say that milk is *made* — I've always associated that with products that require at least a nominal amount of manufacturing/processing (e.g. butter, cream, yoghurt).

For the raw produce though, I can't really recall anything using *made* but more specific terms like *grown*, *harvested*, *farmed*, *raised*, etc.

So in this context, does anyone has a suggestion what might be a more descriptive, or more appropriate word? The best I can come up with is *milked* but that sounds awfully clumsy.

Alternatively, if people have milk bottles from their side of the world that say something similar, then it could just be me that thinks it's a bit clunky.

Comment: Well, you just used *produced* yourself. Without even noticing. That's how natural a word choice it is. So go with that one.

Comment: Well there are ten times as many instances of ["butter made in ireland"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22butter+made+in+ireland%22&oq=%22butter+made+in+ireland%22&aqs=chrome.0.57j60l3.913&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) as there are of ["butter produced in ireland"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22butter+produced+in+ireland%22&oq=%22butter+produced+in+ireland%22&aqs=chrome.0.57j60.7921&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). I can see OP's point, but it doesn't seem to bother a lot of people.

Comment: Yes but @FumbleFingers the OP is asking about milk and is quite clear that other products -- butter is an example -- could be "made."

Comment: @JAM: You're quite right. I only found half-a-dozen relevant instances of ***milk** made in ireland* - but obviously they must make/produce/milk the stuff there, to make/produce all the Irish butter and cheese.

Comment: More pondering on my side, I think the reason made doesn't sound quite right to me is that I've only tended to use it in a direct sense, as in: I'd say cows make milk, but those in the dairy milking the cows don't. Eh. It's probably just me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dictionary.com says that *milk* is "liquid **produced** by mammals". Perhaps *produced* would be better. Cows "make" milk and they "produce" milk, and both sound normal and natural and idiomatic to me (American-speaker): either word should work. The problem for me with this advert is the meaning of "*Permeate Free*". What a strange name for milk!

Comment: Per [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milk_permeate),  “Milk permeate is a by-product of the dairy production process, formed after ultrafiltration ... [for cheesemaking].  Permeate has a watery consistency, and is green in colour due to the presence of B vitamins. It consists of lactose, water, vitamins and minerals.  Permeate may be added to fresh milk as part of a process called standardisation, to keep consistent levels of fat and protein in the product”

Comment: The permeate controversy is so far mainly limited to Australia, hence its mention on Western Australian milk

Comment: @MarkBeadles I think you have had the Eureka moment here. Is that an Australian flag on the milk bottle label, lower left corner? If so, I think that must be the answer, just as you said. In the U.S., we don't (yet) have a permeate controversy. "With acidopholus" or "without rennet" or raw versus pasteurized are what I am accustomed to seeing ;o)

Comment: Indeed, it is a West Australian bottle of milk (the brand being Woolworths Select if you were curious - the weird W-like-but-resembles-more-of-a-green-pumpkin is their icon)

Comment: @jwpat7: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 4):

I've seen labels like "Product of", "Produce of" being used on food labels and I think that it may be more apt in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the alternatives to *made*, *produced*, and the OP's *milked* in the context of milk production are:

- Drawn
- Collected
- Extracted

All three terms [appear to be used](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=milk%20drawn%20from,milk%20extracted%20from,%20milk%20collected%20from&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=). "Drawn in WA" sounds fine to mine ears. "Draughted in [WA]" might also work; but it's technically a [term from the beer industry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draught_beer) with slightly different connotations.

Comment: All those sound reeeeally gross to me.